# Add <br/> to string in variable

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I want to show the XML schema on the browser page.

I need to add breakline `<br/>` to string to show info.

I tried like this:

```
<div>
    @XMLSchema
</div>
@code {

private string XMLSchema = "<?xml version='1.0'?>" +
        "<Employee>" +
            "<Employee>" +
                "<FirstName>First</FirstName>" +
                "<LastName>Second</LastName>" +
                "<ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>" +
                "<Email>email@xyz.com</Email>" +
                "<Address><br>" +
                    "<City>City</City>" +
                    "<Street>Street</Street>" +
                    "<StreetNr>1</StreetNr>" +
                    "<HouseNr>1</HouseNr>" +
                    "<Zip>01123</Zip>" +
                "</Address>" +
            "</Employee>" +
        "</Employees>";
```

}

And this does not work. I know is like text and can't work. Another special has is don't work too.

[image]

Is there another way to paste an XML record with fields in "<>" in HTML?

I don't know how I can do this without adding another variable to any single record. Someone can help me?

Comment: have you tried adding linebreaks...? `\n`

Comment: Yes and \r\n also don't work

Comment: Why do you define the html structor as a sting instead of in the upper html part of the razor file?

Comment: In your posted example, the `<br>` tag does not include the "/" character. It should be `<br/>`.

Comment: You need much more than a few `<br>`  tags. The indenting before the `"` is misleading, you don't have that much structure info.

Comment: There are online convertor APIs, google "xml to html"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this but the best would be to define the html structor in the html part of the razor file and reference to the variables instead of define it as a string.
To avaoid your `'<'` are rendered you need to escape them by `&lt;?`. Same for other Special caracters.
This is why your solution not work, the whole string is not rended by the html engine, include the `<br>`. But that is good because otherwise also `<Address>` and other xml-tags would be rendered.

```
<div>
&lt;?xml version=&#39;1.0&#39;?&gt;&quot; 
    &quot;&lt;Employee&gt;&quot; 
        &quot;&lt;Employee&gt;&quot; 
            &quot;&lt;FirstName&gt;First&lt;/FirstName&gt;&quot; 
            &quot;&lt;LastName&gt;Second&lt;/LastName&gt;&quot; 
            &quot;&lt;ContactNo&gt;1234567890&lt;/ContactNo&gt;&quot; 
            &quot;&lt;Email&gt;email@xyz.com&lt;/Email&gt;&quot; 
            &quot;&lt;Address&gt;<br>quot; 
                &quot;&lt;City&gt;City&lt;/City&gt;&quot; 
                &quot;&lt;Street&gt;Street&lt;/Street&gt;&quot; 
                &quot;&lt;StreetNr&gt;1&lt;/StreetNr&gt;&quot; 
                &quot;&lt;HouseNr&gt;1&lt;/HouseNr&gt;&quot; 
                &quot;&lt;Zip&gt;01123&lt;/Zip&gt;&quot; 
            &quot;&lt;/Address&gt;&quot; 
        &quot;&lt;/Employee&gt;&quot; 
    &quot;&lt;/Employees&gt;&quot;
</div>
```

Comment: That is a lot of manual labour.

Comment: There are a lot of online converters, but I think the request was just to do it once.

Comment: THX. I forget about converters.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not pretty sure I think Code will work fine like this..

```
<Employee><br/> +
            <Employee><br/> +
                <FirstName>"First"</FirstName><br/> +
```

Comment: Try it. Either the <br> is text or <Employee> is fake HTML.

Comment: The Code is not in HTML it's in XML